# How to Find Duplicate Sets in a List

Tags: list-manipulation

Given the list below, I would like to find the sets within that list that are identical according to the order of their elements, generate that set, and show the number of times it appears in Lst. For example, in the below the identical sets are {N20029,N31055} which appears 2 times and {N19155,N31055} which appears 3 times.

```
Lst={{N20029,N31055},{N19155,N31055},{N18163,N31055},{N19155,N31055},{N18017,N31055},{N17149,N31055},{N17111,N31055},{N19155,N31055},{N20029,N31055}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tally gives you the count, and select picks only those that occur more than once.

```
Select[Tally[Lst], #[[2]] > 1 &]

{{{N20029, N31055}, 2}, {{N19155, N31055}, 3}}
```

Comment: bill s: Thank you very much!!! ... prg

Answer (score 5):

**Counts** function also can be used for finding duplicates:

```
Select[Counts[Lst], # > 1 &]

<|{N20029, N31055} -> 2, {N19155, N31055} -> 3|>
```

Comment: very clever!! ... nice idea too! ... prg

Answer (score 0):

```
PositionIndex[Lst]//Cases[a_:>Rule@@a/;a[[2]]>1][Transpose[{Keys[#],Length/@Values[#]}]]&
```

> ```
> {{N20029, N31055} -> 2, {N19155, N31055} -> 3}
> ```

Or

```
PositionIndex[Lst]//Cases[a_/;a[[2]]>1][Transpose[{Keys[#],Length/@Values[#]}]]&
```

> ```
> {{{N20029, N31055}, 2}, {{N19155, N31055}, 3}}
> ```